# Inheritance in sails js

Tags: inheritance, sails.js

**I have an identity model. I want to inherit user and userGroup models from identity model. how can I implement this in sails js?**

Answer (score 0):

Well if you have some methods which can be used in all models you can define them in config/models.js those methods will be available in all models.
Eg:

```
module.exports.models = {

  helloWorld: function() {
    console.log('Hello World');
  }
};
```

Other than this you can extend one model from an other. It is explainled in detail at 
https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/1504